# How to Configure module in Admin Panel in Orchard Cms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am new to orchard i had made a simple module using MVC and Entity Frame work ..The module is simple Crud application.I had integerated this module on my orchard site and this module works fine on front end.But i had problem how to configure same module on admin panel in orchard i want to do these functionalities on admin site

Comment: Please do not cross-post... https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/449039

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a controller called AdminController or decorate a controller with the [Admin] attribute (using Orchard.UI.Admin).

Then to create a menu item create a file called AdminMenu.cs in the route of your project with the following code:

```
using Orchard.Localization;
using Orchard.UI.Navigation;

namespace MyFirstModule {
    public class AdminMenu : INavigationProvider {
        public Localizer T { get; set; }
        public string MenuName { get { return "admin"; } }

        public void GetNavigation(NavigationBuilder builder) {
            builder.Add(T("My admin menu item"), "50",
                menu => menu.Add(T("My admin menu item"), "20", item => item.Action("Index", "Admin", new { area = "MyFirstModule" })
                    .Permission(Permissions.ConfigureRobotsTextFile)));
        }
    }
}
```

This will add a menu item that links to your action. Then you can do whatever admin stuff you want :)